# clang-format removes markdown-style linebreaks in doxygen comments

Tags: markdown, doxygen, line-breaks, clang-format

Doxygen allow to use markdown-style formatting which make in-code documentation much better readable compared to HTML-style.

A markdown line-break consist of 2 or more spaces at the end of a line:

```
/**
 * @brief short description
 * @details longer description with markdown line-break by 2 spaces  
 * next line with more longer description...
 */
```

Unfortunately clang-format removes all spaces at the end of a line. (Actually it should do so in most cases.)

How can I prevent it from doing so?

I tried to use

```
CommentPragmas: '  $'
```

and

```
MacroBlockBegin: "  $"
MacroBlockEnd: "^"
```

But that did not work.

The only solution I found so far is using `// clang-format off` and `// clang-format on` or HTML-style `</br>`.
I do not like both, as both are not that good in terms of readability and easy to forget.

**EDIT:**
I am using Ubuntu clang-format version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1 from Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
I am calling clang-format with the following command line:
`clang-format -i --style=file headerFile.h`
To narrow down the problem I striped down my `~/.cland-format` file to:

```
BasedOnStyle: Google
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? You wrote "Unfortunately clang-format removes all spaces at the end of a line." does this imply that the file written to disk and given to doxygen to be processed doesn't contain the 2 spaces at the end anymore? In the later case it is, in my opinion, not a doxygen or markdown problem but an editor  (in clang mode) problem. Which editor are you using (so people with knowledge about that editor can give some insight)?

Comment: @albert  
I am using doxygen 1.9.1 - If there is another way to make well readable and well looking line-breaks I would take it.  
Yes, file written to disk by clang-format does not contain any trailing white-spaces any more. (Usually that is exactly what I want, but not for markdown linebreaks in doxygen-style comments.)  
I am using VSCode by the way, but that should not have any impact on clang-format.

Comment: Doxygen 1.9.1 is a from January 9, 2021, the current doxygen version is 1.9.8 (but this has no influence on the current problem). The only think I can think of is to use an empty line.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/59630492/1657886and the mentioned feature request there. Did you look at `ReflowComments=false`

Comment: @albert Yes, I tried `ReflowComments: false` - trailing whitespaces are still removed.